# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \binom{n}{3} \frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$ I know that $\binom{n}{3}$ and  $\frac{1}{n^{1.1}}$ converge. I thought rewriting the limit as $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6n^{1.1}}$ might help but I'm unsure where to go from here.

Comment: You seem to have it. Distribute the numerator to find a polynomial of degree $3$ in $n$. Then, divide each term by $6n^{1.1}$. The leading term is $n^{1.9}$ which approaches $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^3+O(n^3)}{6n^{1.1}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1.9}+O(n^{1.9})}{6}=\infty$$

Comment: Do you mean lower case, $o(\cdot)?$ Because $n^3+O(n^3)=O(n^3).$